# Bind List of UControls to a Controls Children property?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, parent

I have got an `ObservableCollection<Button> buttonList;` (this can be any other control: `TextBox`, `TextBlock` or even a `UserControl`).

I want to bind this `List` via `DataBinding` to a parent control (lets say a `Grid` or a `WrapPanel`,...)
Is this somehow possible? `Children` property is read only.
I do not want to do this in the program code -> Dont iterate through the list and add every item to the children property.
I want to BIND the List to a parent control -> the View is automatically updated, every time I add a new Item to the List.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), and bind your collection to [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx).

And don't forget to read Dr. WPF's articles: [ItemsControl: A to Z](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/). This is second time I'm mentioning this blog today here, but he really-really deserves to be mentioned in every post related to collection of items and bindings :).

Cheers, Anvaka.